# Can I extend, in Java, a Kotlin delegating class?

Tags: java, kotlin, decorator, delegation

I'm trying to extend, in Java, a Kotlin delegating class and get the following error:

> Cannot inherit from final 'Derived'

See code below.

What I'm trying to do is decorate a method of a class.

Any idea why Kotlin defined `Derived` as final? Is there a way for `Derived` to not be final so I can inherit it?

Java:

```
new Derived(new BaseImpl(10)) { // Getting the error on this line: `Cannot inherit from final 'Derived'`
};
```

Kotlin:

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}

class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b
```

* Example from here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Kotlin classes are final in by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance).  Mark the class as `open` to extend it (whether from Kotlin or from Java):

```
open class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b
```

The fact this is a delegating class should have no impact on Java interop (although I haven't tried it).